# android-How to protect a file from copying or seeing by users

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm working on an application that it took me about 2 whole month to collect data. 
how can I protect my database and files? because of a big size of database, I zipped it (with password) and put it in asset folder. I can unzip it.

2 questions:

1. where I can extract it that no one can access it even though they have a rooted device ?
2. after extracting my database from zipfile ,I want to copy it to my application database . is there anyway users can access the database ?

Comment: Does the application regularly need to read/write this database? If so, there is *nothing you can do* to stop a dedicated user from accessing its contents.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart . thanks for the reply . I can have 2 database , one for my datas and one for other things that needs to change . I just want to protect it . is there anyway ?

Comment: Think about this: Your application needs to take a series of steps to read data from that database. Any determined attacker can take those exact same steps. If the CPU can access the information, an attacker can.

Comment: The real question is: If this information is so valuable, why do you have to include it with the application on the users' devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how smart an attacker you're expecting.  If you're expecting the average user, don't worry about it- just put it in your data directory, they'd have to root the phone to see it.  From a power user you can encrypt the files.  From a determined hacker that won't work-  he'll decompile the apk and find the key.  You can pass the key from a website, but a good hacker will run it under a debugger and find the key in memory.  The best way to secure most of the data would be not to have it in the app but only download what you need via webservice as you need it, but that will cost money and time.

Comment: If someone root his phone, can they see the data folder and copy the database ?

Comment: another question , if I zip my database in asset folder with a password and unzip it in my application , is it still possible the attacker could get the password ?

Comment: Yes, if they root the phone they can copy the file.  And yes, if you use a zip password they can still get it-  you need the password in the app somewhere to unzip it.  Of course at that level of protection you'd need to be programmer with some reverse engineering skills to get it, not just a user.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no way to hide your files from user sight. they can access your resources sometimes so easy. but you should encrypt your data.

You can use SQLCipher library to protect your data. see http://sqlcipher.net/

Although it has some overhead but you can distribute your data in a safe way.
Hope it can help you

Comment: And the symmetric key goes where... in the application, where it can be easily recovered?

Comment: I guess SQLCipher has nothing for this problem. But we can get the password(symmetric key) from a secure web service. and the easy way is hiding password in application for example generate the password with code and using other tricks. but I know the last way is not completely secure but make it hard to attack. In my opinion the best way is getting password from SSL web service. Hope you share your idea with me

Comment: An attacker can then use whatever information is in the application to  manually connect to the SSL webservice (on his desktop) and download the password, and unlock the database.

Comment: yes. you're right. I forget to say my experience. I had this problem. I prepare a native function with NDK and ask the function to give me the password but some check is required before returning password to check another people can't use my native library.